# PHP and shortcode displaying '0' instead of correct number

Tags: php, wordpress

On Wordpress I've created some PHP code to go to a URL and pull the information; it's the Etherscan API which I want to use to find the balance of an Ethereum address. This is my code:

```
function eth_accountAmount(){
$request = wp_remote_get('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=VYTX1PQH4C1AF5DV7J57CRFQ9ARUDNJ3MX/');
if (is_wp_error($request))
    {
    return false; // Bail early
    }

    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($request);
    $data = json_decode($body);
    foreach($data->result as $result);
        $result = $result / 1000000000000000000;

echo $result;
    }


add_shortcode('eth_account_Amount', 'eth_accountAmount');
```

I tried to create a shortcode, so I could display this information on the site. However, when I place the shortcode, it just displays the number zero. I want to get the result number from the json, the 40807168564070000000000.
The division part of the code is to turn that number smaller, from wei to ethereum.

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=balance&address=0xddbd2b932c763ba5b1b7ae3b362eac3e8d40121a&tag=latest&apikey=VYTX1PQH4C1AF5DV7J57CRFQ9ARUDNJ3MX/  -  the api link

I just want to point out that I'm relatively new to coding, especially PHP, so sorry if it takes me a while to understand anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for the foreach loop there since the API doesn't return an array

Instead of this:

```
foreach($data->result as $result);
    $result = $result / 1000000000000000000;
```

Put in this:

```
$result = $data->result / 1000000000000000000;
```

Comment: THAT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Press the little tick beside my answer to accept it ( https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work )